# Prevent Form Submit for Invalid Email Address

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, email-validation, onsubmit

I'm using this tool:
https://www.edq.com/real-time-email-validation/

... to validate that an email address actually exists.

This tool works properly, but the user can still submit the form even if the validation fails. What do I need to add to the code, to not allow the user to submit the form if they have entered an email address that doesn't work?

The code snippet for executing the validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var $plugin = new emailValidation(              
          $( "#email"), {
            token: "[hidden]",
            proxyPath:  "[hidden]",
            featureVersion:  "1.0" ,
            timeout: 10000,
            inlineMode: true,
            showLoading: true,
            onSuccess: function (data) {
            // onSuccess callback implementation
            },
            onError: function (jqXHR, status, errThrown) {

            },
            messages: {
                emptyEmail:  "Please enter email.",
                error:  "Please contact Experian QAS support.",
                timeout:  "Timeout.",
                success: "yay!"
            },
            styles: {
                success: "success",
                successInline: "success-inline",
                error: "error",
                errorInline: "error-inline",
                loading: "loading",
                correctionEmail: "correctionEmail",
                emailPicklistHeader: "emailPicklistHeader",
                emailPicklist: "emailPicklist",
                picklistItem: "picklistItem",
                picklistItemText: "picklistItemText",
                closeButton: "closeButton",
            }
          }
      );


        </script>
```

Comment: Can you link to the plugin docs instead of the product page?

Comment: _“This tool works properly”_ - it was only able to return “unknown” for several existing addresses I tested … I don’t really see what the value in that would be? // The validation method you have shown appears to be asynchronous, so you would have to block the user from submitting the form until you got a positive response from this asynchronous call.

Comment: @CBroe - you have to complete these two lines in order to test this: token: "[hidden]",
proxyPath:  "[hidden]",

Comment: @Luca - Sure: https://www.edq.com/documentation/apis/email-validate/api/

Comment: @juneallison I was referring to the online version of their tool.

Comment: @CBroe - I was finally able to duplicate your experience (with numerous emails). So for now, we're not using the email validation tool.

Answer (score 1):

The key is in the widget events: `onSuccess`and `onError`. Using them you can do that in many ways, e.g.:

1. Disabling the submit button:

   ```
   onSuccess: function (data) {
       $('#mySubmit').prop("disabled", null);
   },
   onError: function (jqXHR, status, errThrown) {
       $('#mySubmit').prop("disabled", "disabled");
   }
   ```
2. Preventing the form submission:

   ```
   onSuccess: function (data) {
       $('#myForm').data("email-ok", true);
   },
   onError: function (jqXHR, status, errThrown) {
       $('#myForm').data("email-ok", false);
   }

   // On form
   $("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
       if (!$(this).data("email-ok")) {
           e.preventDefault();
           // show an error message 
       }
   });
   ```

In both cases you will have to wait for the service's response and then manage your form. I think the option #2 is the better, but #1 is also ok.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried both of these solutions and neither one worked. I obviously replaced myForm or mySubmit with the proper IDs. What else might I be missing? I tried replacing "email-ok" with "verified" per the documentation. My form tag looks like this: <form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" id="SampleForm"> And I do have a hidden field that looks like this <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://thankyoupageurl.com">

Comment: @juneallison what do you mean with *not worked*. You need to check your console(F12) for errors or event debugging the code to see what really happened.